# Create a right-to-left ProgressBar

Tags: android, android-xml, android-progressbar

I am using the ***Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal*** ProgressBar and I want to keep it like that, but right-to-left.

so at 0% it's on the right and goes to the left as it progresses.

any help?

Answer (score 3):

Use `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` in progress bar:

```
<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="100"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:progress="80" />
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

Start the progress at 100% and simply decrement instead of incrementing.

```
x.setProgress(100);
x.setProgress(85);
etc
```

Comment: The problem is that i want the drawables to be the other way around as well.